# cloud platform for managing and emailing lists of members

Tags: communication, email

What suggestions are there for a reliable and easy to use hosted cloud based platform that will hold members (~50) email addresses and allow forming lists of members that can be emailed, from a standard email client (eg to addresses such as volunteers@xxxx.org.uk or trustees@xxxx.org.uk).

Platforms I have found so far are either (i) unreliable at delivering mail (probably because of recipients' mail server's spam checks) or (ii) complex (eg google apps) or (iii) require our members to sign up on a service they don't all want (eg yahoo groups).

Comment: Any list server or Google Groups will accomplish this.  Is this all you need for your community?

Comment: Not that your question is off-topic, but I suggest you take software recommendation questions to [softwarerecs.se]

Answer (score -1):

I was looking to fill a similar need when I found wiggio.com. Hopefully you will find it as useful as I have.

**EDIT:** Initially I was looking for a solution to the common "reply all" problem of group members replying to emails, as this group is not using a common mail server/service. We also have members that are resistant to signing up for a new service and Wiggio doesn't require it. You can add users three ways,

- Enter the email addresses of anyone you want to add to the group in the Email addresses field.
- Select recipients from your email address book(s) by clicking the email contacts link.
- Import recipients from a spreadsheet by clicking the spreadsheet link.

You can also create subgroups like

> (eg to addresses such as volunteers@xxxx.org.uk or trustees@xxxx.org.uk)

Should you have the need as we did, you can have multiple admins.

Once our members were exposed to Wiggio, they began to see the value of the additional tools available which you can see below.

From there site:

> Wiggio enables group communication and collaboration. Using Wiggio, you can hold group discussions, assign tasks to group members, poll members, share calendars and schedules, upload and manage group files, and communicate using live conference calls, video conferences, chat rooms, texts, emails, and voice mail.

Comment: That would be way overkill for someone just wanting a mailing list.

Comment: @Jan Doggen Based on your logic, no one should ever offer any multi-purpose answer.  If you want to be overly critical, perhaps you should down vote an opinion based question.

Comment: Could you [edit] in some of the specific benefits you found with this platform?  Right now this resembles a link-only answer, and we prefer that answers contain enough information to evaluate them.  Thanks.

Comment: I will update as requested this evening.

Comment: You made an edit that changed one character and had a couple sentences in the revision summary.  I assume you meant to add that to your post and typed it into the wrong box, so I fixed that for you.  Please feel free to edit further.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to edit from phone whilst in a dentist chair.